# Recursive calling make file with variable assignment not working

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am working on few modifications in GNUmakefile of our build system.

Right now we have some part of processing in shell script where we wanted to move that part of code to GNUmakefile.

Shell snippet :-

```
args="TEST=1 PROJECTS=\"\""
make $args test_target
```

Note:- `PROJECTS` variable should be defined and it's empty.

Now we wanted to move that code (running make) in GNUmakefile where i am trying to call the make itself.

GNUmakefile snippet

```
ifdef PROJECTS
  DIRS := ...
endif
....
$(MAKE) DISABLE_TEST=1 PROJECTS=""
```

I want to do some processing inside `if` condition above. But while running make i notice that its not even going inside if check. When i was calling via shell script , it is working fine as expected. Can you please help how we can resolve this issue?

Comment: Perhaps no one has yet told you about [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please show us enough of the makefile that we can reproduce the error, especially the part that defines `PROJECTS`.

Comment: And, probably a typo, but it should be `ifdef` not `Ifdef`... make (like all right-thinking tools) is case-sensitive :)

Comment: No, its not case sensitive. It was just a typo when positing the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use

```
Ifdef PROJECTS
  DIRS := ...
endif
```

`DIRS := ...` is run only if `PROJECTS` has non-empty value.

When you run shell script :

```
args="TEST=1 PROJECTS=\"\""
make $args test_target
```

`PROJECTS` is *not* empty but contains `""`